# Questions about discrete signal energy calculation

Tags: discrete-signals

I'm looking at the definition of signal energy (e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_%28signal_processing%29), [cnx.org](http://cnx.org/content/m11526/latest/)). For discrete signals, it's defined like the following, where $x(n)$ holds the signal:

$
Energy = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |x(n)|^2
$

So my questions:

1. For a windowed, finite signal like `double signal[256]`, the sum is from 1 to 256 (or 0 to 255 in a program) rather than $-\infty$ to $\infty$, right? (I don't even know how I would sum over infinity.)
2. Why does the energy formula have the absolute-value operator $|...|$? The result of taking the absolute value is squared anyways to produce a positive value, so taking the absolute value seems to be pointless. Is it because the $x(n)$ can be complex, so the [absolute value of a complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Absolute_value_and_argument) would be the scalar from Pythagoras' theorem?

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual value is always obtained by mathematical manipulations rather than by explicit computation by adding terms"? How can you get a final actual value unless you do perform the summation?

Comment: Yes, I know the convergence of a geometric series sum. However, I don't see why that is useful here. Why would the values of $x(n)$ take the form of 1, $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, ...? The signals that I'm reading (microphone, accelerometer, etc.) certainly don't have values like that.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but as I said, the data that I'm reading (e.g. from microphone, accelerometer) doesn't look like an exponentially decaying signal, or at least it doesn't look like it.

Comment: You're a mathematician and not an engineer, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Yes. No need to sum up an infinite number of zeros.
2. Yes, it is because `x(n)` could be complex. If we didn't take the absolute values of the complex numbers ([Euclidean norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Euclidean_norm_of_a_complex_number)), a signal containing
   $[\dots,0,0,a+ia, a-ia,0,0,\dots]$
   would have an energy of zero (instead of $4a^2$) although it contains non-zero samples. For real numbers however $|a|^2 = a^2$ and the absolute value doesn't matter.